# Go generics: is it possible to embed generic structs?

Tags: go, generics, struct

I am working on my master's thesis and I'm indirectly working with the "prototype" for generics in Go (go2go).

I wonder if it is possible to use composition and embed a generic struct (with go2go of course)?

I want to do something like this:

```
type A[T any] struct {
    a T
}

func (a A[T]) F() T {
    return a.a
}

type B[T any] struct {
    A[T]
}

func main() {
    b := B[string]{A[string]{"Hello"}}
    fmt.Println(b.F())
}
```

I would get this error message which is referring to the call to “Println” in the main-function: “type B[string] of b does not match A[T] (cannot infer T)”

A non-generic version of this might be this (which works and prints “Hello”):

```
type A struct {
    a string
}

func (a A) F() string {
    return a.a
}

type B struct {
    A
}

func main() {
    b := B{A{"Hello"}}
    fmt.Println(b.F())
}
```

I am not very familiar to this new generic aspect in Go, so it might be that I am doing it wrong? Or is it impossible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible to embed a *generic struct* in the form you present:

```
// type-parametrized struct
type A[T any] struct {
    a T
}

type B[T any] struct {
    A[T] // embedded
}
```

Your code snippet works just fine on the [GoTip playground](https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/CNfHwlI4Dbq), which unlike the old playground is kept up to date with Go master branch. (Anyway Go 1.18 is already released in beta).

Note that in all cases `A` must be instantiated with a type, both in the struct and in variable declarations:

```
type B[T any] struct {
    A // cannot use generic type A[T any] without instantiation
}
```

Finally, the type param doesn't have to be inherited from the embedding struct. Therefore

```
type C[T any] struct {
    A[string] // fine
}

type D struct {
    A[string] // fine
}
```

In this case, when instantiating a variable of type `C` or `D`, you must init the field `A` with the same type param:

```
c := D{A[string]{"Hello"}}
```

---

What is **not** possible is to embed the type parameter directly:

```
type A[T any] struct {
    T // embedded type param
}
```

The current generics proposal [does say](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#embedded-type-parameter) that this should be possible:

> When a generic type is a struct, and the type parameter is embedded as a field in the struct, the name of the field is the name of the type parameter.

However it was decided to leave this out of Go 1.18 ([Source](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/49030#issuecomment-954336867)).

Answer (score -1):

The go2go playground is an experimental thing. It doesn't support all valid generic programs.

See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44689, it seems type embedding has problems.

Main implementation without bugs/deficiencies will come later.